# How to get variable from another instance of the same class?

Tags: c++, function, class, sfml

Im using SFML to make a simple fighting game.
I have a class called Fighter that I use to make two objects.
In main:

```
Fighter fighterOne;
Fighter fighterTwo;
```

Both fighters modify the same variables, mainly isLow() and isGuarded().
To check collision between the two fighters I call checkHit() in updateFighter() (basically if the fighter updates a move, check if it hit) I check the collision in my collision.h class

Note: I chane which fighter is currently being updated with a bool called isRight. if its true, it modifies the 2nd fighter, else, it modifies the first one.

```
void Fighter::updateFighter(Sprite& fighter, Sprite& otherFighter, bool isRight)
{
    if (Keyboard:isKeyPressed(attack)
    {
        //animates the attack
        collision.checkHit(fighter, otherFighter, isLow, isGuarded, lowAttack, isRight);
    }
}
```

Problem is, with the above, Im trying to check the value of isLow of the opposite fighter object (fighterTwo). But when i call it like this, it goes off the currently being used isLow, which belongs to fighterOne. How do I pass fighterTwo's isLow value to checkHit instead of fighterOne's?

Comment: Perhaps you should store the sprites inside the `Fighter` object, and then pass the `Fighter` object (or reference to it) instead?

Comment: With your architecture, it seems you need to pass `figtherOne/Two.isLow` to `Fighter::updateFighter`, unless you can recover `figtherOne/Two` (of type `Fighter`) from `otherFighter` (of type `Sprite`).

Comment: If I understand correctly (not sure that I do) isn't `otherFighter.isLow` what you need? (also is it a variable `isLow` or a function `isLow()` because your question has it as both in different parts).

Comment: @Galik sorry no isLow is stored in Object Fighter not type Sprite

Comment: Then you need to reference to that other fighter - as a parameter most likely.

Comment: Im not sure how to reference another fighter, in the fighter class. @Galik

Comment: Does the code that calls this function have access to both fighters?

Comment: No, checkHit() is called in updateFighter() which is in the Fighter class. The two Fighter objects are made in main().

Comment: One possibility could be that each time an object is created the Fighter class keep a trace of created objects in a static vector of pointers. However, it could be simpler to have two classes, the Fighter class, and a class owning the Fighter objects and managing the process

Comment: @Damien I got to the point of passing the other other Fighter as oppositeFighter from main to updateFighter as a parameter. But im on the point where my isLow wont evalute to be true anyways so it wont work

Comment: I don't understand why isLow won't be evaluated correctly. Could you provide a short code (MWE) that focuses on the problem?

Comment: I finally got it to evalutate properly. Problem was it was being set to true but then immediatly being set to false by another function. I just set it to when the crouch key is not pressed, it inverts it. The passing fighter object thing above works fine